# How to get the SET_TIME permission

Tags: android, device-owner

I am developing a device owner app.
In the app I'm trying to gain the SET_TIME permission by using:

```
DeviceOwnerHelper.getInstance().getDevicePolicyManager().setPermissionGrantState(new ComponentName(this, DeviceOwnerReceiver.class), getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Manifest.permission.SET_TIME, DevicePolicyManager.PERMISSION_GRANT_STATE_GRANTED);
```

But this method does not work? Please help!

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate and it does not solve my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your app as system/app in order to achieve that. In short a short way to say it you have to run your app under the folder /system/ or system/priv-app in some devices.

I am setting the time in my app using the shell with this command: (I have root access)

```
adb shell su 0 date -u [timethatyouwant]
```

edit: I typically use [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cerberus-support-forum/breIGakPnas/98Jv04TjAgAJ) commands to run my app as system/app

Don't know if I helped :p just look for it ;)